# Des-serializar JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Estoy trabajando con una API que me entrega una respuesta en formato JSON y no sé cómo poder deserializar la respuesta para obtener los valores que necesito, estoy intentando con la libreria Gson pero no la entiendo, la respuesta que obtengo en la siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "detectedLanguage": {
      "language": "en",
      "score": 1.0
    },
    "translations": [
      {
        "text": "hello programmers",
        "to": "en"
      },
      {
        "text": "Hola programadores",
        "to": "es"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

necesito obtener ambos `"text"` y `"to"`, espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: Por favor muestra el código Java que te falla y qué error da para poder ayudarte mejor. Debes decidir si optas por GSon  o no para poder tener un punto de partida desde el cual ayudarte.

Comment: Nos deberías mostrar lo que has intentado. ¿Cómo has utilizado la librería gson? ¿Te ha dado algún fallo o simplemente no has sabido utilizarla? Nos hace falta ver código para poder ayudarte

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano no he sabido utilizarla, lo unico que tengo, es la peticion web que retorna ese json como string

Comment: Ok, entonces haz alguna prueba mirando esto: http://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide y si no te aclaras o no te funciona, edita tu pregunta con lo que hayas intentado